# how to replicate a character with regex/sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a script that indents text with four spaces:

`echo ${SOMETHING} | sed 's/^/    /g'`

My IDE complains that I am using four consecutive spaces in regex.

Is there is a way to rewrite this to tell sed, "[space] * 4"?

Comment: Your IDE complains about indentation?!

Comment: sed doesn't have string repetition operator.. you could use perl, but the question is not clear.. how does IDE come into picture with sed?

Comment: `sed 's/^/ /;s/^/ /;s/^/ /;s/^/ /'`?

Comment: If your IDE complains about "spaces in regex", it's wrong, because the spaces are not in a regex, it's a replacement string where regex syntax is meaningless.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: This is a problem with your IDE.  What you're doing is perfectly OK.

Comment: IDE is RubyMine.  Interestingly, PyCharm doesn't complain.  For sure, this could be an IDE/plugin issue with syntax interpretation.  It highlights the statement as needing refactor, not as error.  (Same way it barks about converting $VAR to ${VAR}.)  Thanks everyone for the commentary.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a more basic issue with quoting. (I cannot speak to your 'IDE' because I think that is unrelated.)

You have `echo ${SOMETHING}`. That should be `echo "${SOMETHING}"` or the shell will interpret the string and defined spacing on the expansion will be lost. (Also, you should avoid using CAPS for Bash variables. Those are by convention reserved for Bash's use.)

Example:

```
$ something="123
> 456
> 789"
```

Now, with quotes:

```
$ echo "$something" 
123
456
789
```

Without:

```
$ echo $something
123 456 789
```

Now, a `sed` to indent those lines works as expected:

```
$ echo "$something" | sed 's/^/   /'
   123
   456
   789
```

Also, the replacement text is a simple string (other than interpretation for capture groups or certain C style backslash expansions.) So doing something like `s/^/ {4}/` does not work. You should also understand that `sed` is line oriented (other than logical range operations) so that the `g` in `s/^/  /g` does nothing. There will only be one substitution per line. (Use Perl for multiline substitutions.)

To have some definable indent, now use Bash string interpretation to your benefit:

```
$ indent=$'\t=>\t'
$ echo "$something" | sed "s/^/$indent/"
    =>  123
    =>  456
    =>  789
```

The `$'\t=>\t'` is ANSI C quoting that supports various [C backslash definitions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings). You need to change the `sed` script to `"` so that the value within `$indent` is interpreted by Bash and then added to the sed script. (Note: POSIX sed does not support `\n` in a replacement pattern. GNU sed does.)

Finally, you can use `seq` or `printf` to get a replication of a character (ie, `[space]*6` for use in sed:

```
$ indent=$(seq -f " " -s '' 6)
$ echo "$something" | sed "s/^/$indent/"
      123
      456
      789
```

Or,

```
$ indent=$(printf "%6s")
$ echo "$something" | sed "s/^/$indent/"
      123
      456
      789
```